# Is it possible to recover a PBKDF2 hashed password?

Tags: java, encryption

Using classes `PBEKeySpec` and `SecretFactory` only, and knowing `salt` and `coded` is there a way to decrypt `coded` to recover `password`?

```
public static byte[] encodePassword(char[] password, byte[] salt) {
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH);
    Arrays.fill(password, Character.MIN_VALUE);
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] coded = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        return coded;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("Error while hashing a password: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        spec.clearPassword();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to recover the password from a password hash algorithm like PBKDF2. The fact it is not reversible is one of the main reasons to use such an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

you **"could"** brute-force the password if you know the key and salt, but that **"would"** take a long time.

one-way encryption is the reason you can't "recover" your password on many sites, only reset, and that is the suggested method for storing passwords and comparing encoded strings during log in.